# How to set pickerOptions inline for ionic datetime picker?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I'm reading `pickerOptions` property in [this link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#properties)

And I'm setting

```
<ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="startDatetime"
              (ionChange)="setStartDatetime()"
              displayFormat="MMM DD,YYYY - HH:mm"
              placeholder="Select Start Datetime"
              pickerOptions="{backdropDismiss:false}">
</ion-datetime>
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried `pickerOptions={{backdropDismiss:false}}` according to [this issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16095) and got syntax error.

I can set it in my js by

```
var customPickerOptions = document.getElementById('customPickerOptions');
    customPickerOptions.pickerOptions = {backdropDismiss:false};
```

What's the correct syntax to set it inline in html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic is in the braces
Give it a try

```
[pickerOptions]="{backdropDismiss:false}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In .TS

```
pickerOptions = {
    mode: 'md'
  };
```

and in HTML

```
<ion-datetime [pickerOptions]="pickerOptions" cancelText="Cancelar" doneText="Hecho"></ion-datetime>
```

Comment: Yeah this works, thanks. I wonder if there is a way to specify the object inline in html

Comment: Only string should be possible. Mark if this helped